# Use foreign key table columns to display data asp.net core mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ssms

I have an Invoice Class with FoodId and UserId foreign keys to FoodItem and User table.

I have the following razor page Index.cshtml from adding a scaffolded item to the controllers folder.

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Invoice>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/SideBar.css" />
<div class="sidebar">
    <a asp-controller="Admin">Main Page</a>
    <a asp-controller="FoodItems">Food List</a>
    <a class="active" asp-controller="Invoices">Invoice</a>
    <a asp-controller="Role">Users & Roles</a></div>
<h1>Invoice</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FoodId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.totalsum)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.quantity)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FoodId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.totalsum)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.quantity)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.InvoiceId">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.InvoiceId">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.InvoiceId">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to list instead of the FoodId and UserId , bring the columns foodname and username from the FoodItem and UserId tables.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve Invoice entity include food and user like this:

```
_context.Invoices.Include(x => x.Users).Include(x => x.Food).ToList();
```

And then in your view write like this ;

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.Name)
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Food.Name)
```

Comment: My Invoice class does not contain Users and Food

Comment: Add them as public virtual Food Food {get ; set ;}

Comment: If I want to retrieve username from AspNetUsers what can i add in the Invoice Model class? public virtual IdentityUser user {get;set;} didnt work

Comment: Check your relation between invoice entity and user . Which table are you referring as user. Make sure userId is a foreign key otherwise it is only an integer.